# How do I disable a monitor in Ubuntu 17.10/GNOME 3.26

Tags: nvidia, gnome, multiple-monitors, monitor, 17.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10/GNOME 3.26. Had some glitches during the transition to GNOME from Unity, as I previously partly had used Ubuntu-GNOME as well, and some extensions were killing each other, ubuntu-dock was not working etc.

I got that right, but can not solve another problem which was introduced with a [bug with 14.04 - a bogus monitor](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1296020) I have since then: My system settings show a monitor that does not really exist, due to my nvidia optimus BIOS which seems to be announcing a VGA monitor.
In the past Ubuntu versions, I could use *gnome-control-center* to just "switch off" this monitor - but as hard as I try, I can not find any button or switch to kill that damn monitor:

[image]
[image]

Did I miss something here comepletely?
Or is it possible that GNOME 3.26 does not provide a tool to disable a monitor?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with Nvidia (as stated in the title and tags on this question at the time of writing). On my system I recently switched from GNOME 3.16 to GNOME 3.26, and at the same time was switching between 2 very different Radeon cards and both had this very same problem but only on GNOME 3.26. At first I thought this was some Wayland problem, but I tried running GNOME 3.26 with Xorg11 and the option was still missing. Seems to be a limitation either of GNOME 3.26 or how it is configured for Debian 9 and its derivatives

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a mistake in the GUI design of GNOME 3.26

Luckily there's an extension on the way that fixes this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/897/turn-off-display/

Comment: Switched to KDE. Can't test that ATM.